# Security error while uploading file

Tags: security, file-upload

I get this error while tring to upload a file :
I'm using cpanel and the move_uploaded_file function and it works fine on localhost.

```
Security Alert

The file you are uploading was rejected by the server.
It probably contents viruses or trojans that can damage your website

Do not attempt to upload it again as your IP address may be blocked.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: would this be a question for your host?

Comment: Most likely it's a blocked extension on the server that you are trying to load it to.

Comment: I mean that whoever is hosting your site may know more about the restrictions it places on file types, or whatever is scanning this file. I don't think you'll find much help for this here since this doesn't look like a programming issue. It looks more like a server configuration or hosting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your server to accept the file, whet to configure depends on your server setup.

It sounds like you are using a third party called cPanel for hosting. Then investigate your file and if you are sure it is none malicious. Try contact them about it. I doubt they will respond and provide a patch:(

Comment: The hosting provider added my domain name in their white list and everything is fine now. Thanks a lot everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Mant times this error occur due to mod_security function enable on linux server. So contact your server administrator for disable mod_security function...

Comment: this error sucks.. i was uploading file. and it was doing well.. after some time it starts giving this error.. dont know what the **** is this